# Extended Properties for for csv file OleDB connection string

Tags: c#, csv, connection-string, oledb

a usual connection string would look like

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\file.csv;Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";
```

but i need a way to specify further parameters like:

- ColNameHeader
- Format
- MaxScanRows
- CharacterSet
- Locale
- Unicode

without using a schema.ini file.

is there a way to define those in the connectionstring, or via registry or any other way, without having access to other files.

i've already looked up http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile and many others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least some of the settings you're after are specified in the registry settings for the JET driver. Look in HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Jet/4.0/Engines/Text.